# How to keep loading sign active until page loads completing.Page comes later after ProgressDialog loading sign stops at xamarin native android

Tags: xamarin.android

**My page load later after ProgressDialog loading sign  stops. Inside my page images list view are loading via GetImageBitmapFromUrl. Can u pls suggest how can I keep loading sign on until my page loads properly....**

```
 public override async void OnActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        var mDialog = new ProgressDialog(this.Context);
        mDialog.SetMessage("Please wait...");
        mDialog.SetCancelable(false);
        mDialog.Show();


        _data = (await ServiceContext.Current.Duas.GetAll()).ToList();
        DuasAdapter adapter = new DuasAdapter(this.Context, _data);
        _lstDuas.Adapter = adapter;

        _lstDuas.ItemClick += LstDuas_ItemClick;

        mDialog.Cancel();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi I have solved by modifying my code below...

```
   public override async void OnActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        var mDialog = new ProgressDialog(this.Context);
        mDialog.SetMessage("Please wait...");
        mDialog.SetCancelable(false);
        mDialog.Show();


        _vdos = (await ServiceContext.Current.IslamicVdo.GetAll()).ToList();
        VdoAdapter adapter = new VdoAdapter(this.Context, _vdos);
        _lstVdo.Adapter = adapter;


        fragsIDActivity.RunOnUiThread(() => mDialog.Hide());
    }
```

Comment: Hi , glad you find the best solution ! If my answer be helpful , remember to vote up it and mark your anaswer :)

Answer (score 0):

From shared code , the reason why not waitting for data loaded may be the follow line :

```
_data = (await ServiceContext.Current.Duas.GetAll()).ToList();
```

You need to check whehter `ServiceContext.Current.Duas.GetAll()` also contains the `await` method . If no , there will no wait to invoke the next line code .

I will show the sample code here , `TaskMethod` can be looked as LoadDataMethod .

if code as follow :

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Start code");
    int codeResult = await TaskMethod();
    Console.WriteLine("End code ：" + codeResult);
}

private async Task<int> TaskMethod()
{
    Task.Delay(3000);
    return 1;
}
```

When I clicked the Button , you will see the result is :

```
01-10 14:14:48.474 I/mono-stdout( 5920): Start code
01-10 14:14:48.510 I/mono-stdout( 5920): End code ：1
```

You will see no wait , then End code . The task has not finished .

If code as follow , you will see as your expected .

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Start code");
    int codeResult = await TaskMethod();
    Console.WriteLine("End code ：" + codeResult);
}

private async Task<int> TaskMethod()
{
    await Task.Delay(3000);
    return 1;
}
```

The result is :

```
01-10 14:19:59.396 I/mono-stdout( 6040): Start code
01-10 14:20:02.455 I/mono-stdout( 6040): End code ：1
```

Now the Code end until Task finished .

Comment: Thanks. is there any OnResume() method at xamarin Android?

Comment: @Md.RayhanKhan What's the meaning about *is there any OnResume()* ? This method exists in Activity of Android . Other `Task` finished methods you need to invoke the Completed method manually . That means if creating a task (when App `OnCreate` ), you need to monitor the task finished to do next thing .

Comment: I am not getting any override activity at Xamarin.android. r u telling about xamarin .android? pls see the screenshot https://prnt.sc/ql6upw . OnResume activity is not exists at Xamarin.android. I may be wrong. Can u pls clarify me. Thanks for ur help.

Comment: @Md.RayhanKhan Hi , which super Activity inherit from , you can show it here . Generally , when creating a new Xamarin.Android project, it inherits from `AppCompatActivity` . In addition, I found that occurs `OnActivityCreated` in your project , however it not in my porject . You can download my shared sample to find where the different is , the sample is a normal Xamarin.Android project /

Comment: @Md.RayhanKhan Sorry for misunderstanding your question not in an Activity . Now I have updated the answer , you can have a look at it when you have time .